# Kendo Grid Edit InLine Custom Validation message e.g. for duplicate Names etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an entity *Location* and I am using the Kendu UI Grid with InLine edit mode. 
The entity owns a property *DisplayName*, which is required and **must not exist twice** in the database.

At the moment, it works to display the *Required* Validation message:
[image]

And it also works to build up a method *CustomValidateModel* called in the *LocationController* Ajax InLine Create method, that checks if the Name is already existing in the database and adds then a *ModelError*. I catch this error then in the *.Events(events => events.Error("onError"))* via javascript and show then the message via javascript popup.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("DisplayName", "Name already exists.");
```

[image]

**And this is the crux of the matter:** I don't want to have this javascript popup message. I want to have also this information below the field, like this "Field required!" message.
I have searched plenty of time, but the most people suggest only this Validation and output via javascript as it works in the moment.

Additionally, the actual problem besides the popup, is, that the record, which the user wants to create in the Grid, is then **disappearing** after confirming the javascript popup.
But for usability, I want that the new line and the input persists. The users should be able to edit the given Name, he wanted to save. And NOT should enter the complete line again. Only the Validation message "Name already existing." should prompt for information.

**Code:**

Location entity:

```
public class LocationDto
{
    public Guid? ID { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Field required!")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

**LocationController Action method:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateInline([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, LocationDto model)
{
    CustomValidateModel(model); // checks if the DisplayName is already existing in the DB
    if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Create and Save the Model into database
    }
    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

**javascript function:**

```
function onError(e, status) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Error:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if (value.errors) {
                message += value.errors.join("\n");
            }
        });
        this.cancelChanges();
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

I hope there is a possibility to get this working in the same way. It would be fine according congruent visualization and an enhancement of usability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With modifying of another answer and trying around, I constructed a working solution:

Location Edit.cshtml Grid Razor:

```
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Events(e => e.Error("onError"))
    .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(e => e.ID);
            ...
        })
    .Create(create => create.Action("CreateInLine", "Location"))
    .Read(...)
    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateInLine", "Location"))
    .Destroy(...)
)
```

Location Edit.cshtml js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onError(e, status) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Error:\n";

        var grid = $('#locationGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        var gridElement = grid.editable.element;

        var validationMessageTemplate = kendo.template(
            "<div id='#=field#_validationMessage' " +
                "class='k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation " +
                    "k-invalid-msg field-validation-error' " +
                "style='margin: 0.5em;' data-for='#=field#' " +
                "data-val-msg-for='#=field#' role='alert'>" +
                "<span class='k-icon k-warning'></span>" +
                "#=message#" +
                "<div class='k-callout k-callout-n'></div>" +
            "</div>");

        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if (value.errors) {
                gridElement.find("[data-valmsg-for=" + key + "],[data-val-msg-for=" + key + "]")
                    .replaceWith(validationMessageTemplate({ field: key, message: value.errors[0] }));
                gridElement.find("input[name=" + key + "]").focus();
            }
        });
        grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();   // cancel grid rebind
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

LocationController.cs

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult CreateInLine([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, LocationViewModel model)
    {
        CustomValidateModel(model);
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var location = _repository.CreateNewInstance<Location>();
            location.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            location.DisplayName = model.DisplayName;
            ...
            _repository.SaveChanges();
            model = MapToViewModel(location);
        }
        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    private void CustomValidateModel(LocationViewModel model)
    {
        var existingEntity = _repository.GetAll<Location>()
                                            .Where(o => o.ID != model.ID)
                                            .Where(o => o.DisplayName.Equals(model.DisplayName))
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (existingEntity != null)
        {
            if (existingEntity.Deleted == false)
                ModelState.AddModelError("DisplayName", "Name already exists.");
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("DisplayName", "Name '" + existingEntity.DisplayName + "' already exists in DB, but deleted.");
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to use the kendo template as in the next answer.

Comment: Also here is the nice trick how to make the handler more generic:

.Events(e => e.Error("onGridServerError.bind({gridId: 'grid_custom_field_options'})"))

JS:  var grid = $('#' + this.gridId).getKendoGrid();

Comment: remove class 'k-invalid-msg' from validationMessageTemplate ==> this add css 'display:none'

Answer (score 11):

We accomplished this in a Grid just like you did on the controller side by adding our custom error to the model state and passing that back to the view.  And then in the onError javascript event we built the validation message ourselves and placed it in the grid.

**Javascript onError:**

```
function onError(e, status) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Error:\n";  

        var grid = $('#gridID').data('kendoGrid');
        var gridElement = grid.editable.element;

        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
             if (value.errors) {
                gridElement.find("[data-valmsg-for=" + key + "],[data-val-msg-for=" + key + "]")
                .replaceWith(validationMessageTmpl({ field: key, message: value.errors[0] }));
                gridElement.find("input[name=" + key + "]").focus()
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Then create a **validationMessageTmpl** (or whatever you want to call it):

```
var validationMessageTmpl = kendo.template($("#message").html());

<script type="text/kendo-template" id="message">
    <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg field-validation-error" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block; " data-for="#=field#" data-valmsg-for="#=field#" id="#=field#_validationMessage">
        <span class="k-icon k-warning"> 
        </span>
            #=message#
        <div class="k-callout k-callout-n">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

As far as why user input is disappearing, I assume that:

```
this.cancelChanges();
```

may have something to do with it.  I believe this does just what it says and cancels all changes.  Which would reset your grid and remove all user input.

**One thing to note:**  The code in the ModelState (also the key in your $.each)  must be the same name as the view model property being used for the column you want to display the error on.

Comment: A good starting point, but the <script> block is not correct built and the grid is false reset.

Comment: kendo template is better than html markup in the string variable as in prev post

Comment: Also here is the nice trick how to make the handler more generic:

.Events(e => e.Error("onGridServerError.bind({gridId: 'grid_custom_field_options'})"))

JS:  var grid = $('#' + this.gridId).getKendoGrid();

Comment: I believe you need to also add 
                    grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                    });  
With this part missing the message will dissapear for example in pop up.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this;

```
DisplayName: {
    validation: {
    required: true,
    DisplayNameValidation: function (input) {
       var exists = CheckName(input.val());
       if (exists && input.is("[name='DisplayName']") && input.val() != "") {
            input.attr("data-DisplayNameValidation-msg", "Name already exists.");
            return false;
           }
         }

         return true;
    }
  }
```

And

```
function CheckName(Name) {
var exists = false;
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CheckName",
        data: "{Name:'" + Name + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,            
        error: function (msg) {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            exists = response;
        }
    });
return exists;
```

}

For further documentation check [kendo demo site for custom validation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation).