# Kendo UI grid Error event

Tags: kendo-ui

After the Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC library to the latest version the following code doesn't work:

```
function Error(e)
{
   var gridName = this.options.table.context.id
   var grid = $('#' + gridName).data("kendoGrid");
}
```

The table property is null. How are we supposed to find the sender from the 'e' which is being passed here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error event in the grid API. There is one in the dataSource (which is what I am going to assume you are referencing.)

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-error

This event returns an instance of the dataSource object with the `this` keyword (You can also access the dataSource with `e.sender`).

The dataSource is not Grid specific, and it seems Telerik has removed the `table` property from the dataSource.

---

This thread has a hack that should get what you want.
[Get a reference to Kendo Grid from inside the error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886651/get-a-reference-to-kendo-grid-from-inside-the-error-handler)

It is in the updated edit.